# How to tell mapserver to ignore a filter?

Tags: openlayers-3, wms, mapserver, map-files

I have a filter that I don't want to use at the launch of the application, only on a certain action. I know there is already a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35293/how-can-i-tell-mapserver-to-ignore-a-filter-that-is-set-in-a-mapfile) about this but it doesn't help me, I actually don't understand both of the answers.

I was in a logic of "my column = value or 1 = 1" to get all my datasets instead of just the filter if it's not called.

Here's what I wrote :

```
FILTER (([ct]='%ct%') or  '%ct%' = '%ct%')
VALIDATION
    'ct' '^[a-zA-Z\-]+$'
END
```

I call my layer with a param on Openlayers 3 with

`url: 'http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1%20&REQUEST=GetCapabilities',
            serverType: 'mapserver',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'aisdata', 'ct':'myvalue', 'TILED': true}
      });`

But all my dataset is returned. (If I remove `'%ct%' = '%ct%'` in my mapfile, the filter is well applied)

Can anyone help me to ignore my condition please?

Comment: I don't understand you question. The expression  "my column = value or 1 = 1" is always true and is the same as not filter at all. What do you mean with "get all my datasets instead of just the filter if it's not called."

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico Let's say I have a layer with a column of animals (chicken, dog, cat). I want them all to be displayed on my map. But I have predefined a filter on my mapfile to be able to select only one type of animal later. Because of my FILTER ([animals] = %animals%) my map will display nothing if I don't provide any parameters. I don't know how to say in my FILTER that I want all my animals first (i.e 1 = 1) if no parameters is provided. And if a parameter is provided, I don't want 1 = 1

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico I know it's always true and I need it to be always true. For (([ct]='%ct%') or  '%ct%' = '%ct%') I want Mapfile (or Postgis?) to check if [ct]='%ct%' returns true FIRST. In my case, it seems that it's always '%ct%' = '%ct%' which returns true. Or what I need is "If I don't have any parameters set, then display everything, despite of my filter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a default value in the VALIDATION block, so that your value defaults to a empty string, and than add a OR condition in the FILER block which check if the value is a empty string:

```
VALIDATION
    'ct' '^[a-zA-Z\-]+$'
    'default_ct' ''  # <-- ct will be a empty string if not provided via URL 
END
FILTER (([ct]='%ct%') or  ('%ct%' = '') )
```

If the database column `ct` does have a numeric type, the previous filter will produce a internal server error, because you cannot compare a empty string with a number. In this case use a numeric value as default, something like 0 or -1.

Comment: Well this actually gives me a 500 Internal Server Error haha I'll check if I have to configure a ' ' = ' ' on Apache or something like that

Comment: OK I kept your idea by giving a default value, instead of '' I set 'default_ct' '1' and FILTER (([ct]='%ct%')  or  ('%ct%' = '1')). Thank you very much !

Comment: Probably the problem with a empty string was, that your column `ct` has a numeric type, so that the condition `'%ct%' = ''` raises a Postgres exception because is a condition NUMERIC = TEXT

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t test this trick with a big map. Ask another question and describe better the problem.

Comment: Note than I expect an issue with single parenthesis. I use double parenthesis to make it work correctly otherwise I got a full table scan. The debug show the Where clause with single parenthesis like that

    WHERE   ( '0' = '0' ) OR ( myColumn= '0' )  AND …

with double parenthesis: 

    WHERE   (( '0' = '0' ) OR ( myColumn= '0' ))  AND …
So use  FILTER ( (([ct]='%ct%') or  ('%ct%' = '') ) )